# Dynamically deleting elements from an array while enumerating through it

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I am going through my system dictionary and looking for words that are, according to a strict definition, neither subsets nor supersets of any other word.

The implementation below does not work, but if it did, it would be pretty efficient, I think. How do I iterate through the array and also remove items from that same array during iteration?

```
def collect_dead_words
  result = @file #the words in my system dictionary, as an array
  wg = WordGame.new # the class that "knows" the find_subset_words & 
                    # find_superset_words methods
  result.each do |value|
    wg.word = value
    supersets = wg.find_superset_words.values.flatten
    subsets = wg.find_subset_words.values.flatten
    result.delete(value) unless (matches.empty? && subsets.empty?)
    result.reject! { |cand| supersets.include? cand }
    result.reject! { |cand| subsets.include? cand }
  end
  result
end
```

Note: `find_superset_words` and `find_subset_words` both return hashes, hence the `values.flatten` bit

Comment: You may wish to edit to clarify the definitions of 'subset' and 'superset'. Of [possible interest](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/classical/features/the-enduring-myth-of-music-and-maths-2307387.html).

Comment: I did leave all that stuff off, because it was outside the scope of the question, strictly speaking, namely how to winnow a collection as I iterate through it. Now we're on to a different conversation, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with based on your feedback (plus a further optimization by starting with the shortest words):

```
def collect_dead_words
  result = []
  collection = @file
  num = @file.max_by(&:length).length
  1.upto(num) do |index|
    subset_by_length = collection.select {|word| word.length == index }
    while !subset_by_length.empty? do
      wg = WordGame.new(subset_by_length[0])
      supermatches = wg.find_superset_words.values.flatten
      submatches = wg.find_subset_words.values.flatten
      collection.reject! { |cand| supermatches.include? cand }
      collection.reject! { |cand| submatches.include? cand }
      result << wg.word if (supermatches.empty? && submatches.empty?)
      subset.delete(subset_by_length[0])
      collection.delete(subset_by_length[0])
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Further optimizations are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. I noticed and edited the unfinished sentence moments before or after you left the proposed edit. Asides: Go Bears! ('65). Is it true that most composers are good at math? Do you now regard yourself as a Ruby composer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is going to go a long way toward helping me with my algo design. I don't know about composers having an aptitude for math, and yes, my definition of 'composer' has had to expand considerably in the past few years. Great to make your acquaintance, @CarySwoveland!

Answer (score 5):

It is inadvisable to modify a collection while iterating over it. Instead, either iterate over a copy of the collection, or create a separate array of things to remove later.

Comment: Except that each word generates a group of subsets and supersets which don't need to be checked anymore, and I want to minimize unnecessary cycles by deleting their contents from the collection.

Comment: I'd use the second approach (using a `Set` instead of `Array`), then testing membership in the set to see if you should skip the current word. Again, you can use `delete_if` as @seph demonstrates to remove the current value, but other than that no iterators support removal during iteration; you will end up skipping things that you don't intend to skip.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is with Array#delete_if. Here's my run at it so you get the idea:

```
supersets_and_subsets = []

result.delete_if do |el|
  wg.word = el
  superset_and_subset = wg.find_superset_words.values.flatten + wg.find_subset_words.values.flatten
  supersets_and_subsets << superset_and_subset

  !superset_and_subset.empty?
end

result -= supersets_and_subsets.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: The subtraction of `supersets_and_subsets` happens too late, i.e., it needs to happen before the `find` methods hit those collections. If "supercomputer" is a superset_word of "sprout", then checking "sprout" means I don't have to check "supercomputer".

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

As I understand, string `s1` is a subset of string `s2` if `s1 == s2` after zero or more characters are removed from `s2`; that is, if there exists a mapping `m` of the indices of `s1` such that<sup>1</sup>:

- for each index `i` of `s1`, `s1[i] = s2[m(i)]`; and
- if `i < j` then `m(i) < m(j)`.

Further `s2` is a superset of `s1` if and only if `s1` is a subset of `s2`.

Note that for `s1` to be a subset of `s2`, `s1.size <= s2.size` must be true.

For example:

- "cat" is a subset of "craft" because the latter becomes "cat" if the "r" and "f" are removed.
- "cat" is not a subset of "cutie" because "cutie" has no "a".
- "cat" is not a superset of "at" because "cat".include?("at") #=> true`.
- "cat" is not a subset of "enact" because `m(0) = 3` and `m(1) = 2`, but `m(0) < m(1)` is false;

**Algorithm**

Subset (and hence superset) is a transitive relation, which permit significant algorithmic efficiencies. By this I mean that if `s1` is a subset of `s2` and `s2` is a subset of `s3`, then `s1` is a subset of `s3`.

I will proceed as follows:

- Create empty sets `neither_sub_nor_sup` and `longest_sups` and an empty array `subs_and_sups`.
- Sort the words in the dictionary by length, longest first.
- Add `w` to `neither_sub_nor_sup`, where `w` is longest word in the dictionary.
- For each subsequent word `w` in the dictionary (longest to shortest), perform the following operations:

  - for each element `u` of `neither_sub_nor_sup` determine if `w` is a subset of `u`. If it is, move `u` from `neither_sub_nor_sup` to `longest_sups` and append `u` to `subs_and_sups`.
  - if one or more elements were moved from from `neither_sub_nor_sup` to `longest_sups`, append `w` to `subs_and_sups`; else add `w` to `neither_sub_nor_sup`.
- Return `subs_and_sups`.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def identify_subs_and_sups(dict)
  neither_sub_nor_sup, longest_sups = Set.new, Set.new
  dict.sort_by(&:size).reverse.each_with_object([]) do |w,subs_and_sups|
    switchers = neither_sub_nor_sup.each_with_object([]) { |u,arr|
      arr << u if w.subset(u) }
    if switchers.any?
      subs_and_sups << w
      switchers.each do |u|
        neither_sub_nor_sup.delete(u)
        longest_sups << u
        subs_and_sups << u
      end
    else
      neither_sub_nor_sup << w
    end
  end
end

class String
  def subset(w)
    w =~ Regexp.new(self.gsub(/./) { |m| "#{m}\\w*" })
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
dict = %w| cat catch craft cutie enact trivial rivert river |  
  #=> ["cat", "catch", "craft", "cutie", "enact", "trivial", "rivert", "river"] 
identify_subs_and_sups(dict)
  #=> ["river", "rivert", "cat", "catch", "craft"]
```

**Variant**

Rather than processing the words in the dictionary from longest to shortest, we could instead order them shortest to longest:

```
def identify_subs_and_sups1(dict)
  neither_sub_nor_sup, shortest_sups = Set.new, Set.new
  dict.sort_by(&:size).each_with_object([]) do |w,subs_and_sups|
    switchers = neither_sub_nor_sup.each_with_object([]) { |u,arr|
      arr << u if u.subset(w) }
    if switchers.any?
      subs_and_sups << w
      switchers.each do |u|
        neither_sub_nor_sup.delete(u)
        shortest_sups << u
        subs_and_sups << u
      end
    else
      neither_sub_nor_sup << w
    end
  end
end

identify_subs_and_sups1(dict)
  #=> ["craft", "cat", "rivert", "river"]
```

**Benchmarks**

(to be continued...)

<sup>1 The OP stated (in a later comment) that `s1` is not a substring of `s2` if `s2.include?(s1) #=> true`. I am going to pretend I never saw that, as it throws a spanner into the works. Unfortunately, `subset` is no longer a transitive relation with that additional requirement. I haven't investigate the implications of that, but I suspect it means a rather brutish algorithm would be required, possibly requiring pairwise comparisons of all the words in the dictionary.</sup>

Comment: I started with the shortest words, eliminating supersets, rather than the other way around b/c finding supersets is a much cheaper routine. When I refactor the code I will definitely consider building the routine on a hash, and creating .subset? and .superset? methods.

Comment: If you edit to add a dictionary, I will run a benchmark.

Comment: Here is a detail which I (perhaps wrongly) thought was irrelevant, namely the precise definition of 'subset': it's basically what you suggest, but excluding strict sub*string*s, i.e. `cat` is a subset of `craft` but not of `catalog` -- while `catalog` *is* a superset of `clog`. With regexes, the question "What am I a substring of?" is a lot quicker to answer than "What am I a superstring of?" However, it may be very different for "Am I a substring/superstring of *anything*?"
You could run it against '/usr/share/dict/words' if you're on a Mac..

Comment: Thanks. Later today I'll use that file (yes on Mac) to run a benchmark against: my code, my code shortest words first and your code. I'll change my subset definition as you suggest. If you want to make any changes to your code (e.g., using a hash), go ahead and do so (preferably with "Edit: ...".

Comment: Is 'at' a subset of 'attractive'? No for 'a*t*******'; yes for 'a\*t*******' and 'a******t***' and '****a\*t***'.

Comment: Good question! No. The subset, however derived, must not yield true when passed into Ruby's `@word.include?(other_word)`